# Help with convergence in p-admissible weights

Tags: partial-differential-equations, potential-theory

While providing examples of p-admissible weights in the book "Nonlinear Elliptic Theory of degenerate elliptic equation" the author used the weight to be $w(x)=1$
and the measure to be lebesgue. I am struck proving the second property which is if $D$ is an open set, $\phi_i\in C^{\infty}(D)$ then, 
$\int|\phi_i|^p dx\to 0$ and $\int|\nabla \phi_i-v|^p dx\to 0$ as $i\to\infty$ implies $v=0$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If $\phi_i \to \phi$ in $L^p$ and $\phi_i'$ converges in $L^p $ then $\phi' \in L^p$ and $\phi_i' \to \phi'$.

Comment: @ reuns Thank You so much for your quick reply.